# Spring: How to @Autowire a Class<T>

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm creating a [fragment repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) and I would like to inject a `Class<T>`, however it doesn't seem to be possible. Is it?

```
public interface MongoRepositoryExtension<T, ID> {

    List<T> findAll(Query query, Class<T> entityClass);

    List<T> findAll(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName);

    UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update, Class<?> entityClass);

    UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update, String collectionName);

    UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update, Class<?> entityClass, String collectionName);

}

@Repository
public class MongoRepositoryExtensionImpl<T, ID> implements MongoRepositoryExtension<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private Class<T> entityClass; // Error

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Query query) {
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Query query, String collectionName) {
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, entityClass, collectionName);
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update) {
        return mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update, String collectionName) {
        return mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, collectionName);
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateResult upsert(Query query, Update update, Class<?> entityClass, String collectionName) {
        return mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, entityClass, collectionName);
    }

}
```

How do we achieve this?

Comment: `Class<T>` is not a Spring managed bean.  It's possible that an instance of `T` is, but `Class<T>` is a metaclass that describes the type `T`.  It is strange to want to autowire this into another object.  You should be able to access that object without Spring's help.

Comment: By "possible" I meant if there's any workaround for this. I'm aware it's not a managed bean. That's not super strange in my opinion as `Class<?>` should be really easy to be determined within Spring's argument resolver.

Comment: True...that could be an extra feature of Spring. Was worth a try I guess.  I'm pretty sure that Spring won't do that unless you can force it to instantiate a Spring Bean of that type explicitly.  As to how to turn `T` into a `Class<T>` object ahead of time (that is, without having an instance of `T`), I can't figure it out.  I've Googled a bit, and there are some answers, but they involve some pretty strange reflection code that I'm not confident enough in to recommend that you use.

Comment: You just enlightened me up! Spring's `ResolvableType` might help me! :)